# Natural Medicine with Battle Medicine

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, healing

If I have [Natural Medicine](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=815), can I use Nature instead of Medicine for [Battle Medicine](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=760)?

Natural Medicine:

> [...] You can use Nature instead of Medicine to Treat Wounds [...]

Battle Medicine:

> [...] Attempt a Medicine check with the same DC as for Treat Wounds and restore the corresponding amount of HP [...]

It seems not, Natural Medicine specifically mentions the [Treat Wounds](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=57) activity. Is this correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### RAW you can't

Battle Medicine uses the same DC as Treat Wounds, but through wording is stating that it's not the same check

> Medicine check with **the same DC as for Treat Wounds**